# C++ audio file converter

Tags: c++, audio, encode

I have a G711 codec, and i would like to convert a wav file and save this. I read a sample.wav file, and convert it with the G711 ITU-T codec, and save the encoded data to an output.wav file.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "G711.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// WAVE PCM soundfile format (you can find more in https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ )
typedef struct header_file
{
    char chunk_id[4];
    int chunk_size;
    char format[4];
    char subchunk1_id[4];
    int subchunk1_size;
    short int audio_format;
    short int num_channels;
    int sample_rate;            // sample_rate denotes the sampling rate.
    int byte_rate;
    short int block_align;
    short int bits_per_sample;
    char subchunk2_id[4];
    int subchunk2_size;         // subchunk2_size denotes the number of samples.
} header;

typedef struct header_file* header_p;




int main()

{
    FILE * infile = fopen("sample.wav","rb");       // Open wave file in read mode
    FILE * outfile = fopen("Output.wav","wb");      // Create output ( wave format) file in write mode

    int BUFSIZE = 512;                  // BUFSIZE can be changed according to the frame size required (eg:512)
    int count = 0;                      // For counting number of frames in wave file.
    short int buff16[BUFSIZE];              // short int used for 16 bit as input data format is 16 bit PCM audio
    header_p meta = (header_p)malloc(sizeof(header));   // header_p points to a header struct that contains the wave file metadata fields
    int nb;                         // variable storing number of byes returned

    if (infile)
    {
        fread(meta, 1, sizeof(header), infile);
        fwrite(meta,1, sizeof(*meta), outfile);
        cout << " Size of Header file is "<<sizeof(*meta)<<" bytes" << endl;
        cout << " Sampling rate of the input wave file is "<< meta->sample_rate <<" Hz" << endl;
        cout << " Number of samples in wave file are " << meta->subchunk2_size << " samples" << endl;
        cout << " ID: " << meta->chunk_id << endl;
cout << "chunk_size" << meta->chunk_size << endl;
cout << "format" << meta->format << endl;
cout << "subchunk1"<<meta->subchunk1_id << endl;
cout << "subchunk1_size"<<meta->subchunk1_size << endl;
cout << "audio_format"<<meta->audio_format<<endl;
cout << "num_channels"<<meta->num_channels<<endl;
cout << "byte_rate"<<meta->byte_rate<<endl;
cout << "block_align"<<meta->block_align<<endl;
cout << "bits_per_sample"<<meta->bits_per_sample<<endl;
cout << "subchunk2_id"<<meta->subchunk2_id<<endl;


        while (!feof(infile))
        {
            nb = fread(buff16,1,BUFSIZE,infile); // Reading data in chunks of BUFSIZE

            size_t ds = sizeof(buff16) >> 1;
            cout << "ds: " << ds <<endl;
            vector<short> vec_src(sizeof(buff16), 0);
            vector<unsigned char> vec_dst(ds, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff16); i++) {
                    vec_src[i] = buff16[i];
            }
            short* src = &vec_src[0];
            uint8_t* dst = &vec_dst[0];
            G711::ALawEncode(dst, buff16, sizeof(buff16));
            unsigned char arr[ds];
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < ds; i++) {
                    arr[i] = *(dst + i);
            }

count++;                    // Incrementing Number of frames




            /* Insert your processing code here*/
            fwrite(arr,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(arr),outfile);          // Writing read data into output file
        }
    cout << " Number of frames in the input wave file are " <<count << endl;
    }
    getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I dont know very well C++, so please help me. If i run this code i get Output.wav file but i cant play. Whats wrong?

Comment: If it's a standard format, it should work with standard libraries. Find out what library is used to write files of this format, and use the API defined by it.

Comment: in fact i dont have to write the encoded audio data to file, but i would like to check my program.

Comment: You assume a .wav file has always the same header. You should be careful with this assumption. Note that nothing will go wrong when you use PCM16. If you treat part of the header as audio data, you hear just some garbage at the start.

Comment: For one, your just blindly copying subchunk2_size. Your comment that it denotes the number of samples is wrong. It is the number of bytes so you need to divide by 2. You need to correct the rest of the header too. For example, the audio_format needs to be change from PCM to a-law.